# Angular UNIT TEST failing for callback methods passed inside .map() inside .pipe() of rxjs

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

## The .ts file code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-breadcrumbs',
  templateUrl: './nav-breadcrumbs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-breadcrumbs.component.scss']
})
export class NavBreadcrumbsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscriptions = new Subscription();


  constructor(
    private _router: Router
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this._router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map(event => this.myMethod())
      ).subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          // ... 
        },
        error: (e) => {
          console.warn(e);
        }
      })
    );
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }

  myMethod() {

    // some logic...

  }

}
```

### my spec file

```
describe('NavBreadcrumbsComponent', () => {
  let component: NavBreadcrumbsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavBreadcrumbsComponent>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const routerStub = {
      events: { pipe: () => ({ subscribe: () => ({}) }) },
      navigate: () => ({})
    };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [NavBreadcrumbsComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub }
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavBreadcrumbsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  it('can load instance', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      spyOn(component, 'myMethod');
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

### Currently getting below error

```
NavBreadcrumbsComponent ngOnInit makes expected calls
Expected spy myMethod to have been called.
Error: Expected spy myMethod to have been called.
    at stack (http://localhost:9876/absoluteD:/projects/work/CHI/CHII2I_landing/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2455:17)
    at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absoluteD:/projects/work/CHI/CHII2I_landing/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2425:14)
    at Spec.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:9876/absoluteD:/projects/work/CHI/CHII2I_landing/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:901:18)
    at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absoluteD:/projects/work/CHI/CHII2I_landing/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:524:34)
    at Expectation.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absoluteD:/projects/work/CHI/CHII2I_landing/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:845:21)
    at Expectation.toHaveBeenCalled (http://localhost:9876/absoluteD:/projects/work/CHI/CHII2I_landing/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2369:12)
    at UserContext.eval (webpack:///./src/app/core/components/nav-breadcrumbs/nav-breadcrumbs.component.spec.ts?:45:47)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:390:26)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:288:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:389:52)
```

---

Currently I am unable to spy and test the myMethod() method toHaveBeenCalled. Since it is being called inside a .map() function and which is in turn inside a .pipe() function I am unable to catch the method invocation from outside. Please suggest how to spy and test the myMethod method (just to expect(myMethod).toHaveBeenCalled())

Comment: Too much code. I can’t spend an hour trying to find the problem - can you trim it down?

Comment: @theMayer I have trimmed down the code keeping the relevant parts.

Comment: @ricksclick : can u confirm whether `(res)` has been received under `.subscribe` ? PLease put a console log and check if you are getting its value

Comment: I’m not a big fan of Karma syntax, and I suspect that there’s something wrong with the way the test is constructed. That being the case, what are you trying to test? It generally does not make sense to test that methods get called within the class you are testing, rather it’s better to test for changes of state.